# How to calculate inverse log_10 in Java?

Tags: java

How do I calculate the following formula(power) in Java :

```
We = inv.log_10[(log_10(W_to) - A)/B]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate 10 to the power of a number in Java?

Comment: Is that what it is? I never used the terms "anti-log" or "inverse log" before.

Comment: Yes, that's what it is.  Look into the `Math.pow` method.

Comment: Then, is it simply 10^([(log_10(W_to) - A)/B])?

If using Math.pow(10,x); where x is the exponent.

Comment: Yes.  Logarithms are the inverse operation of "to the power of".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125065/discussion-between-user1478983-and-david-wallace).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find anti log then you need to think mathematically right?

Following Link will help you:

```
http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/util/Logarithm.html
```

Comment: Seems a bit pointless to me, when Java comes with `Math.pow`.  Why download another library to do something that's already in the JDK?